# Spring Boot 2 + ZUUL + EUREKA+ SSO + Error: Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-tool-suite

Estoy configurando un SSO con ZUUL y Eureka, guiandome del tutorial https://github.com/Baeldung/oauth-microservices/tree/master/2x pero cada vez que entro a http://localhost:8081/ose, recibo el siguiente error:

```java
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: sso-service
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
```

No entiendo exactamente que balanceador de carga esta solicitando, ya que según el ejemplo no veo en ningún momento nada al respecto.

**Mi configuración es la siguiente:**

**Eureka:**

Main class:

```java
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceDiscoveryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceDiscoveryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Zuul Gateway:**

Main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ZuulGatewayApplication {

    @Bean
    public UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer userInfoRestTemplateCustomizer(LoadBalancerInterceptor loadBalancerInterceptor) {
        return template -> {
            List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
            interceptors.add(loadBalancerInterceptor);
            AccessTokenProviderChain accessTokenProviderChain = Stream.of( // @formatter:off
                new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(), 
                new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(), 
                new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(), 
                new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider()
            )// @formatter:on
                    .peek(tp -> tp.setInterceptors(interceptors)).collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), AccessTokenProviderChain::new));

            template.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProviderChain);
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true

server.port=8081

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

zuul.routes.sso-service.sensitive-headers=
zuul.routes.sso-service.path=/sso/**
zuul.routes.sso-service.strip-prefix=false
zuul.routes.ose-service.sensitive-headers=
zuul.routes.ose-service.path=/ose/**
zuul.routes.ose-service.strip-prefix=false
zuul.add-proxy-headers=true

security.oauth2.sso.login-path=/login
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://sso-service/sso/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=/sso/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.client.client-id=sso-client
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=xxxxxx
security.oauth2.resource.jwt.keyValue=xxxxxx
```

**Authorization Server:**

main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class AuthorizationServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthorizationServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=sso-server

server.port=8082
server.servlet.context-path=/sso
server.use-forward-headers=false

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

**ose-service:**

main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class OseServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OseServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=ose-service

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

security.oauth2.resource.jwt.keyValue=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
security.oauth2.resource.id=ose-resource-rest-api
security.oauth2.resource.service-id=${PREFIX:}resource
```

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro, pero tu error suena a que tu proyecto esta buscando a un servicio con el nombre de `"sso-service"`, pero este no se ha regristrado  a `Eureka`.